# c# Upload file to webserver [the remote server returned an error 405 method not allowed]

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, file-upload

I am currently developing a teacher-student system in which the professor has the ability to upload a file to a server and the student can download it.
The problem i'm having is that i cannot for the love of life get my files from my computer upload to a specific server.
Here is that part of the code done in C#:

```
openFile.ShowDialog();
location = openFile.FileName;
fileName = openFile.SafeFileName;
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.UploadFile("http://WEBSERVER-EXAMPLE/",fileName);`
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying method=Post/Put and/or setting the correct mimetype?

Comment: i tried using the "Post" method and it gave me the 404 Error: Not found. And with the "put" method, i still get the 405 error.

Comment: Have you tried specifying mime-type and accept-headers?
And could you maybe post the code of the upload module? That helps a lot in understanding your problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I found my error, i started using the FTP service from a server and it worked. I totally dismissed this method for uploading files... as of now.